# Generate a unique reference number with todays date

Tags: c#, sql-server, unique, increment

I am using #C and SQL.

I'm looking to generate a unique reference number like XN-ddMMyyyy-0001

- XN - just random text noting what reference number belongs to what program
- ddMMyyyy - is DateTime.Now
- 0001 - is the unique reference I want to auto increment.

If SQL has XN-26112020-0001 then create XN-26112020-0002 and so on....

How would I go about doing this using SQL database and C#?

I'm guessing it'll require SQL IF NOT EXIST (SELECT) INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: Easiest is to save parts to separate fields and then concatenate for display purposes. Is this for Access db? Can't you use Access autonumber field type to generate the unique sequence? If not Access then which db - add db tag. Also, if every value will always have XN as a part, there is no reason to save it, just concatenate literal text.

Comment: SQL is not a database, it is a language used by many db platforms. Do you mean SQLServer or MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server, sorry I'm use to shortening SQLServer to SQL.

Comment: Then why not use GUID feature?

Comment: I would assume that number would be at max 9999 then? You could create a trigger and update a column that would be your uniqueid you are looking for?

Comment: I recommend using a sortable date, e.g. yyyymmdd. Solves all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use `SEQUENCE` like below:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seqrefno
AS INT 
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1 
GO


SELECT 'NX-'+CONVERT( CHAR(6),GETDATE() ,12) +'-'+  CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR seqrefno AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a lot of work to generate sequential values for each combination of `XN-ddMMyyyy` - it is much simpler if the unique reference is truly unique. You can do this by storing the first part of the reference and using and identity column for the unique part and then combining them in a computed column. Of course if you are generating a lot of records then you'll need more than 4 digits.

```
create table MyTable (
    -- ... other columns
    BaseReference varchar(12)
    , uniqueReference int identity (1,1)
    , FullReference as BaseReference + '-' + convert(varchar(4),uniqueReference)
);
```

If you truly have to make it unique only for the base reference then you need to do something like the following which requires an exclusive table lock to avoid the possibility of 2 processes adding a duplicate reference at the same time:

```
declare @BaseReference varchar(12) = 'XN-26112020-', @UniqueReference int;

begin tran;

-- Lock the table until the transaction is complete to ensure no duplicates
-- Get the current max value of the unique portion
select @UniqueReference = max(try_convert(int,substring(Reference, 13, 4)))
from dbo.MyTable with (tablockx)
where substring(Reference, 1, 12) = @BaseReference;

set @UniqueReference = coalesce(@UniqueReference,0) + 1;

insert into dbo.MyTable (/*Other Columns*/ Reference)
  values (/*Other Columns*/ @BaseReference + format(@UniqueReference,'0000'))

commit;
```